# how does the backward of stacked LSTM run?

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRjME.png)

as we all know, if the layer of LSTM is 1, the backward gradient is pass from the last time step.but in stacked LSTM, if the layer is 2,as shown in the pic, the gradient in the red frame is passed from two dimension, so how to calculate the gradient?